# MongoDB: Difference between $redact and $filter

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have read the mongo docs and seems bit confused whether `$filter` and `$redact` operators are the same and if not how? 
I have used both of them to get the subset of arrays in the document. `$redact` seems to be the same, but the mongo definition seems different. However, the examples on mongo site are demonstrating array subset operations for `$redact`.

I have clarity on `$filter` operator, it works exclusively for arrays, while no clarity on `$redact`.

Whats the advantage of `$redact` over `$filter`? And what are its use-cases ?

for example:

```js
db.shirts.aggregate([{
   $redact: {
      $cond: {
         'if': {
             $or: [
                { $eq: ['$color', 'red'] },
                { $not: '$color' }]
              },
         then: '$$DESCEND',
         'else': '$$PRUNE'
     }
  }
}])
```

versus:

```js
db.shirts.aggregate([{
    $project: {
      colors: {
        $filter: {
          input: '$colors', 
          as: 'color', 
          cond: {
            $eq: ['$$color', 'red']
          }
        }
      }, 
    }
}])
```

Those 2 snippets achieve the same in different ways. Is there an advantage to one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation operations perform operations on group of values and return computed result.

MongoDB executes aggregation operations into stages with output generated from execution of each stage serves as an input to next stage into an aggregation pipeline.

$redact is a stage of aggregation pipeline which is used to restrict the contents of the documents on basis of specific condition.

An expression specified as an argument of $redact stage resolves to $$DESCEND, $$PRUNE, or $$KEEP system variables .

$filter is an operator used into $project stage of aggregation pipeline  filters an array returning a subset of an array on basis of specific condition.

Comment: I think the OP meant to ask about differences in performance of a `redact` query and a `filter` query that produce the same output.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the advantage of $redact over $filter?

In most of the use cases, I have found `$filter` to be more performant compared to `$redact`

What you can do is run `explain("executionStats")` on both of the aggregation query so that you can see the performance differences yourself.

Example:

```
db.shirts.explain("executionStats").aggregate([{
   $redact: {
      $cond: {
         'if': {
             $or: [
                { $eq: ['$color', 'red'] },
                { $not: '$color' }]
              },
         then: '$$DESCEND',
         'else': '$$PRUNE'
     }
  }
}])
```

[A similar comparison can be found here](https://github.com/simagix/keyhole/wiki/Aggregation-Framework:-$match,-$unwind,-$redact,-and-$filter)